# Use MSSQL with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to connect to MSSQL database from AWS Lambda (using python) and really struggling to proceed further.

I tried many options with pyodbc, pypyodbc, pymssql they work on local development machine (Windows 7), however AWS Lambda is unable to find the required packages when deployed on AWS. I use ZAPPA for deployment of Lambda package.

I searched through many forums but unable to see the anything moving ahead, any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks,
Akshay

Comment: How you connect to SQL Server from Python shouldn't have anything to do with how your application is deployed. Have you tried to connect from a Python application locally? If no, do that first. There's a *ton* of information, tutorials, guides. *Then* look into how to package your code for AWS Lambda deployment

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your response. Yes, I have successfully connected to the MSSQL database locally using python, but the issue comes when I want to deploy that as a complete zip package into AWS Lambda, I am still trying to reach to that point.
Thank you once again for your suggestion :-)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos found a a solution to connect (read/write on MSSQL DB) and following are the steps:
1) did 'pip install pymssql' on amazon EC2 instance as under the hood Amazon uses Linux AMIs to run their Lambda functions.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html
2) copied the generated .so files and packaged inside the Lambda deployment package

hope this will helps others as well who are searching for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I tried different trial and error steps and ended up with the following one which is working fine in AWS Lambda, I am using PYMSSQL package only.

1) did 'pip install pymssql' on amazon EC2 instance as under the hood Amazon uses Linux AMIs to run their Lambda functions.

2) ***copied the generated '*.so' files*** and packaged inside the Lambda deployment package

Below is the folder structure of my lambda deployment package

[image: pymssql-lambda-aws-python]

Let me know if you further need help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do `import cython` together with `pymssql` in your code.